# Is it possible to call a function when hovering an operator/property?

Tags: interface, add-on, operator

I have a button that changes the visibility of a thing (not explaining it since is not related to the question), and I would like to preview the changes that clicking the operator will make in the scene. And, when un-hovering the button, discard that preview.

Im looking for some short of hover like function in operators. I think is like a basic functionality but I wasnt able to find anithing in the manual nor in the internet.

Is it possible to execute some code when hovering a button?

Comment: Buttons are only pressed in Blender's UI and there is no functionality for executing functions when hovering over a button in Blender's Python API. You would have to make something for that yourself. It doesn't seem like it would be a very easy thing to achieve.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thanks for the info friend. Indeed. I saw some people on the internet using the modal function to kinda track the mouse position to check if the mouse was between the button rect, but I found it was unnecessarily complicated